# Need to have dynamic background image in Ruby on Rails view

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to have a dynamic background image in a Rails view. I've tried a few different code samples I've found on Stack Overflow for dynamic background images, but none of them have worked for me. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<style media="screen">
  .my-image { background-image:url("mypicture.jpg");}
</style>

<div class="my-image"></div>
```

It works fine when I substitute a URL from the web (i.e. instead of "mypicture.jpg", I used "http://lorempixel.com/400/200" which worked fine). However, it doesn't seem to work when I try to use an image stored on my hard drive. It also works fine when I hard code the CSS file. And yes, the image is stored at \app\assets\images. I am using Ruby 2.3, Rails 5.0 and Windows. Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an **image_url**:

```
.my-image {
   background-image:url(image_url(mypicture.jpg));
}
```

Take a look at [AssetUrlHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) in the Ruby on Rails API docs for future information.

Comment: This didn't work for me...I tried every sort of image_url, image_path, asset_path, etc. syntax and nothing worked. I finally got it to work just by putting the image in the 'public' folder rather than the asset pipeline. I'll mark this as the solution since it got me on the right track :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggered by Shah, this is supposed to work :

```
background-image: image-url("mypicture.jpg")
```

or

```
background-image: asset-url("mypicture.jpg", image)
```

Did you try to run `rake assets:precompile` , then restart your server ?

Comment: Just tried that...still no luck. The only thing that worked for me is putting the images in the public folder.